File is not found in docker
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY TotechsThunder.sln TotechsThunder.sln
COPY mock/programminglanguages/programminglanguage.js mock/programminglanguages/programminglanguage.js
COPY src/LightningLanes/API/LightningLanes.csproj src/LightningLanes/API/LightningLanes.csproj
COPY src/LightningLanes/Core/LightningLanes.Core/LightningLanes.Core.csproj src/LightningLanes/Core/LightningLanes.Core/LightningLanes.Core.csproj
COPY src/LightningLanes/Jobs/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost.csproj src/LightningLanes/Jobs/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost.csproj
COPY src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Logics/Logics.csproj src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Logics/Logics.csproj
COPY src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Tests/Tests.csproj src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Tests/Tests.csproj
COPY src/Technologies/Technologies.csproj src/Technologies/Technologies.csproj
COPY src/Projects/Projects.csproj src/Projects/Projects.csproj
COPY src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj
COPY src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj
COPY src/Gateway/Gateway.csproj src/Gateway/Gateway.csproj

RUN dotnet restore TotechsThunder.sln

COPY src/Technologies src/Technologies
COPY src/Contracts src/Contracts
WORKDIR /app/src/Technologies
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/src/out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Technologies.dll" ]


I’m having trouble with the programminglanguage.js file. This file contains master data, which my ASP.NET Core app uses during initialization to seed data into the database migration. Everything works fine in my development environment, but when I run the project in a Docker environment, the file can't be found.
When I run docker compose build, the service builds successfully. However, when the project runs in Docker, I encounter the following error:
2024-09-21 04:40:15 Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/app/..\..\..\..\..\mock\programminglanguages\programminglanguage.js'

Here’s the code I’m using to read the file for seeding during migration:
string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string relativePath = @"..\..\..\..\..\mock\programminglanguages\programminglanguage.js";
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(baseDir, relativePath));


In Docker, the issue seems to stem from the relative file path not being resolved correctly. I’d appreciate any help in resolving this so the app can find the file in the Docker environment.
Files location in my project

What I did try:
Trying to check inside the docker container if there's a programminglanguage.js file in there, but the release + docker environment file system is just too unfamiliar for me to do an investigation
What I'm expecting:
programminglanguage.js is copied inside the container and the path
string relativePath = @"..\..\..\..\..\mock\programminglanguages\programminglanguage.js";

that retrieve the file should not result no file

I always find it useful, when I ask question, to extract problem I am having out of my project. It is very unlikely for someone to set up entire project just as you did to solve the problem. That's why it is important to post minimal example - so extract your problem out of your project. For example, if one particular file copying fails, most probably it could be reproduced with setup: 1 single file, one Dockerfile and that's it. Then, personally, I would copy the two, run some docker command against Dockerfile. Now, I won't as I don't have time to analyze your project and try to replicate it.

Solution
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY TotechsThunder.sln TotechsThunder.sln
COPY src/LightningLanes/API/LightningLanes.csproj src/LightningLanes/API/LightningLanes.csproj
COPY mock/programminglanguages/programminglanguage.json mock/programminglanguages/programminglanguage.json
COPY src/LightningLanes/Core/LightningLanes.Core/LightningLanes.Core.csproj src/LightningLanes/Core/LightningLanes.Core/LightningLanes.Core.csproj
COPY src/LightningLanes/Jobs/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost.csproj src/LightningLanes/Jobs/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost/LightningLanes.HangfireJobHost.csproj
COPY src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Logics/Logics.csproj src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Logics/Logics.csproj
COPY src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Tests/Tests.csproj src/Features/GitHubFeatures/Tests/Tests.csproj
COPY src/Technologies/Technologies.csproj src/Technologies/Technologies.csproj
COPY src/Projects/Projects.csproj src/Projects/Projects.csproj
COPY src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj
COPY src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj
COPY src/Gateway/Gateway.csproj src/Gateway/Gateway.csproj

RUN dotnet restore TotechsThunder.sln

COPY src/Technologies src/Technologies
COPY src/Contracts src/Contracts
WORKDIR /app/src/Technologies
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/src/out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/out .
COPY --from=build /app/mock/programminglanguages/programminglanguage.json ./mock/programminglanguages/programminglanguage.json
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Technologies.dll" ]


The problem may reside in using backslashes \ instead of normal ones, since Docker is running Linux-based images, Windows file paths will not be recognized well

Posting as an answer because comments require more reputation(???)

